# Determine probability areas of large data set

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value

Beforehand: Im not advanced in mathematics, but Im stuck on a problem I need to solve for my masters thesis.

I broke it down to the following situation:

I have a pool of possible values (105000), ranging from 0 to 200. I am picking 866 of these values. Now I want to define an area, in which the sum of the picked values lies with a certain probability, lets say 75%.

So far I calculated the average value (94) and created kind of a box-plot, so what I know is:
15% of the data is lower than 17, 25% is lower than 27, 50% is lower than 70, 75% is lower than 110 and 85% is lower than 140. The average value is 94. And I am picking 866 of those values. It reminds me of a "ball picking without replacement" situation, but that doesnt really help me...

I hope you understand my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have determined an histogram of the cumulative probability of the data.
From that you can roughly estimate the variance. Or ,maybe you can compute that directly from the data.

Once you have the mean and the variance, $868$ is quite a large quantity to allow you to use
 the Central Limit theorem.
Also $868$ is small enough wrt to the total amount of data, that you can consider 
each picking to be independent of the others.
(you may disregard the "sampling without replacement" effect, if you are going to do so).

By normalizing your data concerning the CDF plot, this turns out to be quite near to a Uniform
Distribution. from that I get a mean of $ \approx 78.9$ and a variance of $\approx 2921.7$, which corresponds to 
a stdv of about $54$.

Now the Central Limit theorem tells us that the sum of the $868$ pickings will be approximately distributed 
normally, with a
mean $\mu = 868 \, \cdot \, 78.9 = 68,485$
and a variance $\sigma ^2 =868 \, \cdot \, 2921.7=2,536,036$
i.e. with a stdv of about $1592$.

*--- reply to your  comments  ---*

a) ${\cal N}\left(  \mu, \sigma  ^2 \right)$ will approximate the distribution of the sum quite well, except on the tails.
Since the Normal has infinite tails, while your sum is constrained within $[0, 868 \cdot 200]$ which 
is approximately $[ \mu \pm 40 \cdot \sigma]$, then you can just trim the $\cal N$ accordingly, and practically you do not need to
re-normalize it after the trimming.

b) The approximation works either as CDF and as PDF. I did not get if your data are continuous or discrete.
If discrete, than approximate with a continuous interval $[s \pm 1/2]$.

c) How good is the approximation with the normal ?
Well it depends of course on:
 - the number of variables summed;
 - how "far from normal" are the addends (yours are almost uniform);
 - how different from each other are the variances of the addends (yours have the same variance).
There are plenty of articles dealing on the topic of bounding the resulting error, and it not the case to reproduce
them here.

d) If you have to deal also with the case that the addends be much less that $868$, say of the order of $10$, 
then you may consider an alternative approach, starting from the assumption that the data distribution
can be well approximated as being uniform.
You can then use the [Irwin-Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution)
which is in fact relevant to the sum of Uniform continuous variables, and which can be well extended to
discrete ones, if the base interval is large enough (even about $10$ vs. the $200$ you have), provided that 
you "center" the discrete values into the continuos range (the $\pm 1/2$ cited above).

e) You do the normal  approximation above for three different sets of data, obtaining three different $\cal N$'s.
*"If I now sum up my three individual sums, Do I just multiply the possibilities, to get the complete probability for that specific outcome?"*
It depends on wich process you want to simulate.
If $s_1, s_2 , s_3$ are always obtained  by summing that number of pickings from that specific population, then
$S= s_1 + s_2 + s_3$ will be surely approximated by
 $${\cal N}\left(  \mu_1 + \mu_2 + \mu_3 \, , {\sigma_1} ^2 + {\sigma_2} ^2 + {\sigma_3} ^2 \right)$$.

Comment: So I would assume that my data set is normal distributed as well? Can I do that? I have a mean value of 94 and a standard deviation of 96, which already sounds a bit weird

Comment: @Elias: not exactly so. The Central Limit T. says that the **sum (average)** of a large number of independent random variables tends to be normally distributed, no matter what (under certain limitations) their actual distribution is. For mean/variance question I will extend my answer.

Comment: @Elias: I have reshaped and extended my answer, hope it is more clear

Comment: I think I got it and it worked, thanks! 

But:
When I want to calculate the probability of a certain sum of values, I use the standard normal table, right? Is the possibility of "evening out" of extreme values included in this already? The only Input I give is the total sum I want to check?

And I will be doing this sort of calculations for more data sets and was wondering about the limits of the central limit theorem. I have read something about 30 picks to be necessary. Would 14 out of 8700 still provide me with scientifically reliable outcomes?

Comment: @Elias added reply to your questions in comment

Comment: The data is continuos, its power production outputs for wind turbines in 10 minute intervalls.

I just dont really understand why the distribution doesnt match my results. I did a lot of "test-pickings" now, to check the distribution. And my simulation nearly always results in the mean value +- 10.000, while the Normal Distribution states that only 40% would lie in that area. I feel like the distribution doesnt really give justice to the multiple pickings and the "evening-out" of extremer values. But in theory it does right?

Comment: @Elias: uhm .. I do not catch exactly what is your problem. I feel some information is missing about how you collect the data (= how they are originated) and how you make the sum. I am an engineer, so I am quite tickled by this problem. When you say that the data are the power output in 10 min. interval, then they are a time series = the values are correlated = they are not independent, to a certain extent. If that is the case, it would be better that you open another post, and better state what actually are your data, how they are collected, and what you need to obtain: physics comes before !

Comment: Ill give you some context:
I modelled the power output of a wind turbine in 10 minute intervalls for 2 years, based on measured wind data. This is the time series of 105.000 values mentioned before and yes they correlate.  Now I included Energy Curtailment measures in my simulation, for times in which the grid is  overloaded and the output needs to be reduced. These happen (in my simulation) in intervalls of 10 minutes, 60 minutes and 120 minutes. The 10 minute curtailments happen 866 times (the number from above). In this times, the power output is reduced by a certain factor.

Comment: These reductions are put into my time series randomly. 
Now, in order to present my results, I need to display what amount of energy is curtailed in these years. But this question does not have a definite answer, since the reductions can happen anytime and the power output is not constant. So I want to present a range of which amounts are possible and probable.

Comment: @Elias: please open another post (here we have exhausted space) and advice me about.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3424904/determine-distribution-of-randomly-picked-values-of-a-time-series

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you have $N=105000$ real numbers that are in $[0,200]$ and you want to find an interval $[a,b]$ such that $p=0.75=75\%$ of the numbers lie in that interval.

If that's the problem, then it is actually simple, just order the numbers and see what's the $pN=78750$ number, let's call this number $r_{75}$. Then $75\%$ of your numbers lie in $[0,r_{75}]$.

It's important to notice that there are many other intervals with this property, the one I gave you was the easiest to build, but depending on what you need you may want to find some symmetric interval around the mean or the shortest possible interval or something else.

Comment: Thats not exactly what Im looking for, I guess it wasnt articulated very well.. 

Of that N numbers, 866 are picked randomly. Then, these picked numbers are summed up and I want to make a statement about the sum. 
"with a probability of 75%, the resulting sum lies within the Intervall [x,y]."

Comment: hmmmmm ok, I got it know... You know the $N$ numbers explicitly or you have the distribution of them?

Comment: I know them explicitly

Comment: I guess in the end the extreme values will even out and the result will most likely lie around 866 times the average value. But how to get there I dont know...